# Nuxtjs /node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant --version FATAL: kernel too old

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, yarnpkg, pngquant

I am trying to run : `yarn install` in my nuxt app
after it finish he show me this error:

> Command failed: /home/theprjk6/public_html/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant --version 
>   FATAL: kernel too old 
>     ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed 
>     ℹ compiling from source